# Overwrite file if exists

Tags: php, file, upload, overwrite

I have a simple file upload script which upload pdf format file to directory. What I need if filename exists I want to overwrite existent file. Can anyone help me with this case? Also I will be very glad if you can give me advice how to add script which will ask: File with same name exists should we overwrite?

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

    $expensions= array("pdf");      
    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors ="Разрешено только формат PDF.";

        if (!file_exists($newname)) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"creditinfo/".$file_name); 
        }

    }
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='Размер файла не должен превышать 2 мегабайта';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"upload_folder/".$file_name);
        echo "файлы загружен!";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: According to [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) - *If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.*

Comment: Just check it is cache problem :( file is overwritten but in browser it shows old file cached. Any suggestions?

Comment: What I typically do is keep a version history of duplicate images, so when I create a link to an image it looks like `/path/to/images/image.png?version=X` and X is incremented every time an image overwritten. This way browsers will create a new cache entry when X changes.

Answer (score 3):

try this piece of code

```
if(file_exists($newfilename)){
        unlink($newfilename);
    }

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $newfilename);
```